# Was Kursk sunk by USS Memphis?

Tags: history, weapons, military

On of the theories in the [Kursk incident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_submarine_Kursk_explosion) suggest that it was sunk by USS Memphis following the collision with USS Toledo. Theory has originally surfaced in 2005 film, but lately allegedly there are some leaks from Russian Navy officers confirming it.

> French filmmaker Jean-Michel Carré, in *Kursk: a Submarine in Troubled
>   Waters*, which aired on 7 January 2005 on French TV channel France 2,
>   alleged that Kursk sank because of a sequence of events triggered by a
>   collision with a US submarine. Carré claimed that Shkval torpedo tests
>   were being observed by two US submarines on duty in the region: USS
>   Toledo and USS Memphis. According to his version, these observations
>   eventually led to a collision between USS Toledo and Kursk. Carré
>   theorized that neither of the subs was seriously damaged in this
>   incident, but the sound of the collision, combined with sounds of
>   loaded torpedo tubes, made the captain of USS Memphis believe that
>   Kursk was preparing an attack on USS Toledo, so he launched a
>   pre-emptive strike against Kursk with a MK-48 torpedo. According to
>   Carré, this attack was successful and was the cause of the powerful
>   explosion within Kursk's hull, sinking the submarine and leaving
>   Memphis and Toledo slightly damaged. Carré claimed that specific
>   damage visible on the Kursk hull was the main evidence of this
>   version, including signs of an initial collision, and a hole left by
>   the torpedo when it entered the Kursk hull. He also claimed that a
>   damaged submarine was sighted leaving the Kursk incident area, and USS
>   Memphis was sighted soon afterwards being repaired in a Norwegian
>   port.

In below screen capture you can see a round hole, which allegedly is point where torpedo penetrated the hull.

[image: Alleged hole -- point of torpedo's penetration]

Question:

- is there any indication that collision actually happened?
- is there any possibility that it was sunk by Mk-48 fired by USS Memphis?

Comment: Great question!

Comment: Great question, but probably impossible to answer with the type of rigor this site demands.  Conspiracy nuters can just pull random crap out their butts and they have a "theory".  To actually refute or confirm this, someone would need access to US Submarine logs, which are classified.  As for the hole, I bet you $1 that if you look at it from another angle, it will appear as a much different shape and the filmer is playing loose with actual facts in this case.  ;)

Comment: @Brightblades: yeah, I'm aware that for next few decades we'll not get the full picture (if we ever get it), but I was hoping for refute on technical basis (like for example the way Mk-48 works). But yeah, they don't call it "silent service" for nothing.

Comment: also, I wouldn't mind partial answer, that would cover the first question.

Comment: I would like to know the tensile strength of the Kursk's pressure hull -- is it close to the HY100 level? Thanks, guys.

Comment: I was one of the wives who flew in to meet my husband in the Berings Strait. We greeted our men while the Russian wives arrived to find news that their husbands were dead. It was a horrifying realization for me at the time.
In addition, we had undercover US agents following us, eavesdropping on conversations while we toured the area. We were not allowed to even MENTION the Kursk. In most situations, I would get an honest run-down from my husband. But that instance was different. He offered limited info when I asked. And each time he told it, the story changed...a clear sign something was amiss

Comment: I could be wrong but I think it's grammatically (or culturally) correct to put the word **The** in-front of a ship name.  So it would be The Kursk and The USS Memphis.

Comment: @MarkRogers Addition of "the" to the name can be done for submarines more so than for surface vessels, but omitting "the" is not wrong for either. Remember that ships are often spoken of as people, by name, rather than objects. Were we to talk about the submarine as "the Oscar III class submarine Kursk" the word "the" would be required.

Comment: @MarkRogers: wiki isn't using "the", see entry for [Kursk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_submarine_K-141_Kursk) and [USS Memphis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Memphis_(SSN-691))

Comment: ok, sure, edit as you wish.

Comment: A Mk-48's behavior is classified, but I can tell you in all certainty that that hole in the side of that submarine did not come from a Mk-48. //submariner

Comment: One, a Mk48 has a proximity fuse. It does not "penetrate". Two, if it *would* actually impact at its top speed of ca. 55 knots, the entry hole (if if would indeed penetrate a hull build to withstand significant pressure) would not be as clean as this. Third, and most importantly, a Mk48 torpedo carries a warhead of 650lb high explosives. If it exploded and ripped the Kursk apart, I would expect the hull to be dented *outward*, not *inward* at the point of impact...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There some additional photos of this round hole at [this page](http://sciencevsnonsense.narod2.ru/istinnie_prichini_gibeli_apl_kursk/) (in russian):

Good quality shoot from unknown source. Text in russian is: "А что значит это отверстие в правом боку подводной лодки" - "And what is meaning of this hole in right side of the submarine". It is clearly seen that hole has very sharp edges on its top and left sides. Also we can see that hole is not round in its low-right side (as it was required in comments, taken from other angle):

[image: Text says: "And what is meaning of this hole in right side of the submarine"; unknown source]

This is a copy from the TV-film discussed ("Kursk: a Submarine in Troubled Waters"):

[image: Frame from TV-film "Kursk: a Submarine in Troubled Waters"]

This photo is labelled: "пресс-центр ГП РФ"; "ГП РФ" is abbreviation for "Генеральная Прокуратура Российской Федерации", so "Press-center of Prosecutor General’s Office of the Russian Federation" (press center of Federal Attorney of Russia):

[image: Text says: "Press-center of Prosecutor General’s Office of the Russian Federation"]

This photo has date mark on it "24' 4'02" = 24.04.2002 and text "район прочного корпуса напротив которого отверстие в легком корпусе. никаких пробоин нет" = "region of strong hull (=inner hull=pressure hull) opposite of which hole in  light hull (=external hull) /is located/. There are no any breaches":

[image: "район прочного корпуса напротив которого отверстие в легком корпусе. никаких пробоин нет. 24.04.2002"]

And finally is frame with labels "росляково. мурманская область. РТР". It has label of Russian federal channel RTR. According to the page, Carre says that this hole was not shown on TV, but it was:

[image: Frame from TV program aired on Russian Federal channel RTR]

There is [interesting phrase](http://www.vif2ne.ru/nvk/forum/archive/180/180510) on military history forum "vif2ne":

```
От  tevolga 
К    All    
Дата    31.10.2001 11:06:44 
Рубрики Современность; Флот;    
Круглая дырка на Курске

Главком пояснил, что ее вырезали водолазы еще в прошлом году, никакого 
отношения ни к возможному столкновению, ни к торпедированию не имеет. Ее
теперь заварят, что бы не было более досужих вымыслов:-)))

C уважением к сообществу.
```

> From: tevolga; To: All; Date: 31.10.2001 11:06:44; Rubrics: Modernity, Fleet
>
> Subject: Round hole on Kursk
>
> Commander-in-chief /of the Navy/ clarified that hole was cut by divers early as in previous year /2000/, no any relation is possible to hypothetical collision or to torpedo attack. The hole will be welded now to limit more of myths :-)))
>
> With respect to the community.

Other phrase is on federal newspaper [forum](http://www.novayagazeta.ru/inquests/53911.html?p=4)

```
Александр _Покровский, 11 август 2012 в 09:24
В "Рубине" мне сказали насчет того отверстия: был технологический разрез.
```

> [Alexander Pokrovsky](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), 11 August, 2012 at 09:24
>
> In "Rubin" (=[Rubin Design Bureau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubin_Design_Bureau), operator of the Raising operation of Kursk) I was told about this hole: was technological incision

The newspaper "Независимая Газета" directly [says](http://www.ng.ru/events/2001-11-01/7_kursk.html) in 2001-11-01:

```
Круглое отверстие на стыке первого и второго отсеков, которое наблюдали 
миллионы телезрителей во время демонстрации видеофильма Главной военной 
прокуратуры, оказывается, имеет искусственное происхождение: часть корпуса 
по просьбе главкома вырезали еще в прошлом году. Когда ее в интересах 
следствия поставят на место, многое прояснится, намекнул Владимир Куроедов.
```

> Round hole between first and second compartments, which was seen by millions of TV viewers at the time of airing of film by Chief Military Prosecutor Office, turns out to have artificial origin: part of hull was cut in previous year (=2000) at the request of the Commander-in-chief /of the Navy/ (=[Vladimir Kuroedov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Kuroyedov)). When it will be returned in place  for investigative purposes, much may become clearer, Kuroedov hinted.

Comment: PS: I can estimate diameter of this hole as 1.5 meters, and diameter of Mark 48 is 533 mm.

Comment: Maybe there exists 1.5m hull-penetrating torpedos, since it may be be so difficult to create enough pressure difference to break all layers of a hull.  Under water bunker busters for submarines.

Comment: Yeah, but there are no any torpedo on USA submarines besides 533mm Mark 48.

Comment: more correctly (there might be prototype torpedoes on US submarines of other types that are secret programs after all), there are only 533mm torpedoes on US submarines, as there are no other torpedo tubes on the boats (and thus anything larger could not be launched).

Answer (score 36):

A torpedo does NOT penetrate the hull of a target vessel, it will have a proximity fuse with possible backup contact fuse and probably a timer fuse as well. So that's one claim already debunked.

[Wikipedia on the Mark 48 Torpedo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_48_torpedo)

Can't find independent verification of this (it's most likely classified what exact fuzing modes exist), but it is consistent with knowledge I have accumulated over the years about torpedoes from several post-WW2 designs (WW2 and earlier designs typically used contact fuses).

[This DOT&E report](http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY1999/navy/99mk48adcap.html) mentions "influence fuzing", meaning magnetic, acoustic, etc. rather than impact or time delay.

> The MK 48 ADCAP torpedo is a submarine launched, heavyweight acoustic homing torpedo with sophisticated sonar and an influence-fuzed warhead. The improved ADCAP torpedo includes all digital guidance and control systems, digital fusing systems, and propulsion improvements, which add speed, depth, and range capability. The Mk 48 class torpedoes are the Navy's only submarine launched torpedoes used for engagement of submarine and surface targets, contributing significantly to the submarines' precision engagement. They are also essential to the force protection role of submarines. There are a number of upgrades to the ADCAP torpedo discussed in the following paragraphs.
>   
>   Every seemingly interesting bit of detail ends after a few words with:
>   More details are provided in the classified version of this report.

[This Powerpoint presentation](http://www.franksemails.com/powerpoint/mk48torpedoshot.pps) (unreferenced, but with photographs) shows the effect of a Mk.48 torpedo detonating to sink an old frigate. Compare the damage done by the warhead exploding under the ship to the supposed "entry hole" :)

As to the collision claim, collisions between submarines have happened in the past so might have happened here, but are highly unlikely to lead to the ships sinking. And if one were to sink, I'd expect the smaller, lighter built one to sink which would be the US submarine. (The Kursk is a lot larger than a US (or Soviet/Russian) fast attack sub.)

Comment: yeah, that's what I've suspected. Although allegedly the under-ship explosion is only used against surface targets.

Comment: under ship is natural for surface targets because it breaks the keel. For submarines, any proximity detonation would create a massive bubble of overpressure in the water near the hull, enough to damage the pressure hull. What happened to Kursk was an internal explosion of a similar warhead, caused by (if my memory serves) the fuel supply of an experimental weapon cooking off.

Comment: At the moment, the DOT&E site is down. I suspect/hope it is temporary.

Comment: Nope: the DOT&E site is still down.

Comment: @Oddthinking it works for me, may it be that your access is blocked by a firewall? That happened to me in the past with a lot of US .mil sites, now working at a US owned company routing all internet traffic through their US HQ, and can access it.

Comment: @jwenting: Are we talking about the same site? [Not just me](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY1999/navy/99mk48adcap.html)

Comment: @Oddthinking yes, that one. Accessed it a few hours ago, was rather quick too.

Comment: @Oddthinking, the [link](http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY1999/navy/99mk48adcap.html) works for me, but not via [dfeojm](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/http://www.dote.osd.mil/pub/reports/FY1999/navy/99mk48adcap.html)

Comment: I see the same as @Benjol - link works, but dfeojm reports it down.

Comment: +1 A retired sub captain I know confirms the under-the-keel attack profile of the MK-48. He adds that such an attack would likely involve the target ship going down with all hands.